# Copy user input from one custom dialog to another

Tags: wix

I have 2 custom dialogs. They are essentially copies of each other. The idea is that there are some scenarios when the user will be presented with both dialogs, and when that happens, it is highly likely that most/all of the data will be the same, but there is a chance that it won't all be the same, and the user needs to be given the opportunity to have different values between the two dialogs.

What I'd like to do is either default the values in the second dialog to the values of the first dialog, or have a checkbox in the second that will copy the values. Either way, I need to be able to set the property values. I can either do it automatically when the user transitions between the two dialogs, or do it upon the user checking a checkbox. I would be happy with either solution.

I've looked into the `SetProperty` element, but from what I understand, that only works on pre-defined MSI actions, and I don't believe any of those actions will work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking in the wrong area.

I ended up going with a `PushButton` as it actually made more sense.

I was able to copy the values when the user clicks the `PushButton` using the `Publish` element under my `UI` element. My `Publish` element looks like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="TargetDialog" Control="CopyButton" Property="PROPERTY_NAME" Value="[SOURCE_PROPERTY_NAME]">1</Publish>
```

I have 4 more of the same publish tag, with the only difference being the property and value attributes.

I hope this helps other people!